If a polyhedral cone has no extremal rays, then it is a linear space
Let $C \subset \mathbb{R}^n$. We say that $C$ is a polyhedral cone if there exist $v_1, \ldots, v_k \in \mathbb{R}^n$ such that:
$$ C = \{ \lambda_1 v_1 + \cdots + \lambda_k v_k : \lambda_1, \ldots, \lambda_k \geq 0 \}.$$
We write shortly $C = \text{cone}(v_1, \ldots, v_k)$. By Fourier-Motzkin elimination theorem, we know that, equivalently, a polyhedral cone is given by a set of homogeneous linear inequalities:
$$ C = \{ x \in \mathbb{R}^n : a_i \cdot x \geq 0, \ \forall i \in \{1, \ldots, m\} \}$$
where $a_i \in \mathbb{R}^n$ for all $i \in \{1, \ldots, m \}$. We will write shortly:
$$ C = \{ x \in \mathbb{R}^n : A x \geq 0 \}, $$
where the matrix $A$ has rows given by the vectors $a_i$ and the $\geq$ sign means that the inequality holds in each component.
For a polyhedral cone $C$, we say that $v \in C$ is an extremal ray if:
$$ v = \lambda u + \mu w, \quad u, w \in C, \quad \lambda, \mu \geq 0 \implies u, w \text{ linearly dependent}. $$
Equivalently, $v \in C$ is an extremal ray if it cannot be written as $v = \lambda u + \mu w$, where $u, w \in C$ are linearly independent and $\lambda, \mu \geq 0$.
This turns out to be equivalent to the following condition: writing $C = \{ x \in \mathbb{R}^n : A x \geq 0 \}$, let $v \in C$ and $A_v$ be the matrix whose rows are the rows $a_i$ of $A$ for which $a_i \cdot x = 0$. Then, $v$ is an extremal ray if and only if $\text{rank}(A_v) = n-1$. From this, it follows that the number of extremal rays of a polyhedral cone is alwyas finite.
My question is the following: is it true that if $C \subset \mathbb{R}^n$ is a polyhedral cone and $C$ has no extremal ray, then $C$ is a linear space?
